# How to remove default Provider and allow users to choose?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, web3-providers

Currently I have MetaMask installed in my chrome browser. And the dApp that I'm building uses the Ethereum provider by default.

How can I not use it as the default Provider, and selects the Provider based on using WalletConnect?

So for example:

user loads dApp page --> No provider selected --> User scans QR with walletConnect on different blockchain network --> Different/Custom Provider is selected

Answer (score 1):

One way you could to it is with Web3Modal, if you want a good plug-and-play solution.

Website: https://web3modal.com/

Github: https://github.com/WalletConnect/web3modal

Try their examples on their website and check their examples on Github for React and HTML, its straight forward. Just configure the providers you want, and implement it on your dApp.